# file.info returning NA values in r

Tags: r

I am trying to get size of files and other details from my directory however it is returning NA values for some files but it is returning details for other files. Below is the code i used. will there be any administrator settings for files to fetch these details??

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
wd <- "F:\\working\\others"
setwd(wd)
#get file list - your list of files would be different
fileList <- list.files()[1:240]
class(fileList)
#result
cbind(
  file.info(fileList)[,c("size"), drop=FALSE],
  x = as.character(file.mtime(fileList))) %>% 
  separate(x,
           into = c("DateModified","TimeModified"),
           sep=" ") %>% 
  add_rownames %>% 
  select(DateModified,
         TimeModified,
         Size=size,
         FileName=rowname)
```

Comment: How confident are you that you have 240 valid files in that folder? I can replicate `NA`s when I extend beyond the length of the file list, not otherwise. Perhaps a better way to limit (without over-extending) the list would be `head(list.files(), n=240)`, which will give you *no more than* 240 elements, less if there are insufficient numbers.

Comment: BTW: you can do `file.info(fileList)[,c("size","mtime")]` instead of two separate calls to `file.info` and `file.mtime` (which is just a helper-function into `file.info`).

Comment: BTW #2: your call to `separate` is dropping the time zone component of the `POSIXct` timestamp. Though I believe `file.mtime` will return the same timezone for all files, are you looking for relative timestamps or are you concerned with absolutes?

Comment: @r2evans yes i am looking for relative time stamps

Comment: @r2evans The main Issue is i could not fetch details for few files only. I would like to know is there something to do with security settings of files like these

Comment: R and "security issues" do not overlap, period. Your options are to (1) infer security problems by the presence of `NA`, or (2) \*shudder\* <strike>elevate privileges of the R process</strike>. I strongly discourage the second option. Vehemently. (R is not and never was designed to deal with permissions or security like that. It is assumed that, as a not-so-general programming language, those types of tasks would be extrinsic to the needs or F.)

Comment: Argggg ... "or F" --> "of R" ... dyslexic typing?

Comment: @r2evans sorry i did not get you

Comment: My last comment ("argggg") was correcting the tail end of the previous comment, which should have ended with *"... to the needs of R"*.

Answer (score 16):

try this:
the trick is in the full.names = TRUE

```
ldir <-  normalizePath("<type here the path of directory>")
finf <- file.info(dir(path = ldir, full.names = TRUE), extra_cols = FALSE)
View(finf)
```

Comment: Can also be built as a pipeline using dplyr and list.files: 
`list.files('./dir', full.names = TRUE) %>% file.info()`

Answer (score 0):

One thing worth noting is that, at least on Windows, R will give you `NA` if the path is a folder. If anyone has this issue, they can use `fs::is_dir()` to identify those and implement a different method (possibly recursing to calculate the latest date).

For example,

```
folder_last_modified <- function(path, depth = "max") {
  # if (depth == "max") { # then, `recursive = TRUE`
    files <- list.files(path, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
  # }
  max(fs::file_info(files)$modification_time)
}

last_modified <- function(path) {
  if (fs::is_dir(path)) {
    folder_last_modified(path)
  } else {
    fs::file_info(path)$modification_time
  }
}

lapply(character_vector_of_paths, last_modified)
```